# Tab index in a sequence

Tags: asp.net, textbox, tabindex, html

I have a set of text boxes and html editors in my form.
I am not able to set the proper tab index.
The tab index moves from the first text box and skips all the controls in between and reaches the last html editor and the third tab takes me to the address bar and then it moves randomly all over the controls.

I now want to remove the tab index for all controls and then assign the index in a sequence programmatically.

Comment: Are you adding the various TextBox controls programmatically? Is this why the tab indexing is getting out of order?

Comment: No, I have not added them programatically, All the controls are in source only..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmm you could use javascript on body load perhaps:

```
var textbox = document.getElementById("textbox");

//removing a attribute such as tabindex
textbox.removeAttribute("tabindex");
```

with jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() { $("textbox").removeAttr('tabindex'); }
```

in [.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.attributecollection.remove%28VS.71%29.aspx) I think you could use Page_Load in your HtmlControl (textbox with runat=server)

```
textbox.Attributes.Remove("tabindex");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can manually assign tab indexes on your controls. There is no need to remove the tab indexes from anything else. Just start with the control you want to be first, give it a TabIndex of 1, and move down the list.

Answer (score 0):

Click View and then Tab Order. You will see Tab Orders for all the controls in your form e.g 0, 0.1, 0.2, 1.0. 1.1 etc.  Just click the number to adjust the Tab Order. Its easy.